# Failing to display image from server directory file

Tags: php, mysql, image, server

I'm failing to display the contents of "uploads" folder.

On the website I've uploaded the image and it goes into the server directory file/ the uploads folder, and then it should fetch and display the image, but it doesn't. Thanks for reading this, I'm happy to hear your suggestions.

```
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


//This is me trying to display the image (all this is in the index.file <main> where my server.php file is included (<?php require_once 'server.php'; ?>)) - 
    <td><?php echo '<img src="'.$target_dir.'" width="100" height="100">'; ?></td>



<main>
<?php require_once 'edit-carteri-server.php'; ?>    

<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>    

<div class="alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['msg_type']?>">    

    <?php
        echo $_SESSION['message'];      
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
    ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>

<div class="container">
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'id12522465_admin') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));        //Savieno ar datubāzi
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM carteri") or die($mysqli->error);                      
 ?>

<div class="row justify-content-center">    
    <table class="table">                   
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Bilde</th>
                <th>Valsts</th>
                <th>Teksts</th>
                <th colspan="2">Action</th>
            </tr>
<?php

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>       
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo '<img src="'.$target_file.'" width="100" height="100">'; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['valsts']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['teksts']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="edit-carteri.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"
                    class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                <a href="edit-carteri-server.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"
                    class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
<td><?php echo '<img src="'.$target_file.'" width="100" height="100">'; ?></td>
```

Not:

```
<td><?php echo '<img src="'.$target_dir.'" width="100" height="100">'; ?></td>
```

Comment: Hi its telling me that the $target_dir was an undefined variable, same with $target_file, I'll just post the whole code containing the include part. Check my original post to see it.

Comment: It's odd that `$target_dir` is being reported as undefined when you clearly define it in the first line of code. Is all of the code shown in your question in the same file?

Comment: no the server code is in the "edit-carteri-server.php" all the rest is in the index file.

Comment: Let's see if your `require_once` is working the way you expect. After this line: `<?php require_once 'edit-carteri-server.php'; ?>` put `echo $target_dir` and see what you get.

Comment: Then your `require_once` is not working as expected. Please edit your question to include the entire contents of `edit-carteri-server.php`. You should also clean up the table: Everything is in `<thead>`. There is no `<tbody>`. Your `<main>` tag is not closed. You maybe want to stop and make a small test page to eliminate everything except the `require...` until you get that figured out.

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippet there it looks like you may just be using the wrong variable, unless that was a mistake in adding the question.

Should be $target_file instead of $target_dir in the image tag:

```
<td><?php echo '<img src="'.$target_file .'" width="100" height="100">'; ?></td>
```

Comment: Hi its telling me that the $target_dir was an undefined variable, same with $target_file, I'll just post the whole code containing the include part. Check my original post to see it.

Comment: Is your require_once working? You might want to try printing out $target_file right after the require to see if its set to anything. Is edit-carteri-server.php in the same directory as the file where it is being included? If not, you would need to put the full path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

To display an image, `src` must point to the path of an image.
Try replacing `$target_dir` by `$target_file`.

Comment: Hi its telling me that the $target_dir was an undefined variable, same with $target_file, I'll just post the whole code containing the include part. Check my original post to see it.

Comment: Maybe the problem is your `upload` directory.
Does it exist in well on the same level as your php file?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand your question, can you explain it to me in layman's terms.

Comment: It's in the admin folder where the uploads folder is also